# How can I sort all my questions by date or by time when they where asked?

Tags: support, questions, sorting

How can I sort all my questions by date (by time) in that list that I get to after clicking on my user's name at the top of the screen (right after the envelope icon)?

---

Update:

I am sorry I forgot to mention that I want my questions to be sorted by the time they were asked, not by the time of their latest responds.

And also, I would want to be able to see the oldest questions at the top of the list (which means that the very first question that I ever asked on "StackOverflow" must be first from top).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Click the button labeled `newest` (on the right hand side) to sort by date of posting, or the button labeled `recent` to sort by date of last activity.

In response to the Update: Click `newest` to to sort by date of asking. There is no way to sort by oldest first in the SOFU interface.

Comment: Hello waiwai933, I am sorry - I forgot to mention some important details in my question. Please, check them out there under "Update:".
Thank You.

Comment: @brilliant: I have updated my answer in response to your update.