# Something broken when voting up and accepting?

Tags: bug, status-completed, voting

Is it just me? I can't accept [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2636849/how-can-i-return-a-dictionary-from-f-to-c-without-having-to-include-fsharp-core/2637819#2637819) answer, I get a little flicker of green, but nothing else.

And I just voted up [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/46703/how-can-i-sort-all-my-questions-by-date-or-by-time-when-they-where-asked/46704#46704) answer 10 times, apparently successfully, though I have to refresh the page every time to see the difference.

Comment: What browser were you experiencing this in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you might want to clear your browser cache.

edit: if anyone can provide repro steps for this, we will look into it.

edit: We deployed improved voting code, so the denormalized counts are always set via live queries of the actual votes in the vote table rather than a brain-damaged `.Score++`.

Comment: Maybe, but check the second answer all the same. I've tried opening it from another browser and I still see the 11 votes: it may be that 9 other people up-voted in the minute I spent upvoting, but I doubt it.

Comment: @ben the denormalized counts were indeed off, which is fixed by the daily scripts. There were no actual votes behind the number, though.

Comment: OK, and now I've managed to accept the other answer, so all's well.

Comment: This is an interesting opening for an exploit, if someone can manipulate the (apparent) number of votes on a post merely by fiddling with code on the client-side.

Comment: @Jeff don't you think this little thing should at least be looked into? Even though the problem will be fixed later by the daily scripts, this has the effect of bumping an answer to the top when sorting by votes.

Comment: @Jeff, just for the record, I still seem to be getting the 'not seeing anything when I vote up' problem - but not on StackExchange sites... And I think the accepting thing may have been the 8-minute (is it?) fastest-gun-stopper.