# Bug: Awarded double rep for accepted answer

Tags: bug, status-completed, reputation, accepted-answer

I noticed this because Jon's tracker was showing +60 for [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2718948/2719060#2719060) (+3 and accepted, so should be 45 rep):

From my rep report:

```
 2   2719060 (10)
 2   2719060 (10)
 2   2719060 (10)
 1   2719060 (15)
 1   2719060 (15)
```

The two accepted answers are nice and everything, but I don't think it was *that* good...

Comment: possible duplicate of http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/47509/accepted-answer-reward-15-awarded-twice

Comment: not really a duplicate, as it keeps happening after the "fix"

Comment: oh come on you show-off!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The duplicate vote has been deleted and I recalced your rep (I shudder when I have to recalc you big hitters' rep :)

Yes, there's a bug in the accepted answer routine - Benjol's two accepted answer vote requests were made **at the same time** which bypassed our checks for previous votes.

We're looking into how to better lock per-user actions; I have some crazy ideas, but I'm probably going to have to ask a question on Stack Overflow :)

Comment: We like to think of ourselves as inbuilt scalability tests ;-p Maybe a nightly script is a better way to go than locking? Just a thought...

Answer (score 3):

Related to [Accepted answer reward +15 awarded twice!](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/47509/accepted-answer-reward-15-awarded-twice)

I think Benjol did it again, probably he found a flaw in the system

In [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/46706/something-broken-when-voting-up-and-accepting) post, He claimed that he could vote 10 times on a particular question and also mentioning about accepted answer.

<sub>I should have look his posts and start answering from now :-)</sub>

Comment: Interesting. Not least because it clearly isn't actually fixed. Unless the "fix" was, "ah, what's the chances of that happening again; pfff" ;-p

Comment: I think Benjol got some kind of superpowers.

Comment: @Marc - In my mind, that's a well known and valid fix for a [shrug report](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2349378/new-programming-jargon-you-coined/2353466#2353466).