# Me = (probably) Idiot... Find my Enlightened Answer!

Tags: support, status-completed, enlightened-badge

So, I was awarded the Enlightened badge within the last day or two here on Meta. Which is fine by me, except it looks like my highest voted answer is 8 upvotes, 0 downvotes. I *suppose* two people could have voted it up, then removed their votes, but it seems like suspiciously unusual timing.

So is this

1) something weird MSO is doing,
2) me being terribly lucky with two upvoters upvoting at the right time (and then choosing to remove their votes)
3) me being stupid and either misunderstanding Enlightened or not seeing my well-upvoted answer?

As requested, screenshot of my +8 answer: 
[alt text http://img534.imageshack.us/img534/1100/mso.png](http://img534.imageshack.us/img534/1100/mso.png)

Comment: You might want to take screenshot on that 8 upvote, 0 downvotes post before someone upvote to make it 10 :D

Comment: Be sure also to indicate the answer in question with a freehand circle. It's not a real question without that.

Comment: Feel free to add a drop shadow to the freehand circle if you want to escalate your issue up the chain

Comment: What is MSO's obsession with freehand circles???

Comment: @Billy ONeal it's either that or waffles and unicorns. At least to me freehand circles are easier to draw than unicorns.

Comment: Unfortunately they are also less yummy than waffles or unicorn too...

Comment: @Billy: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19478/the-many-memes-of-meta/19775#19775 - And stop misusing punctuation marks!

Comment: @waiwai: In case of doubt: 3)

Comment: In-jokes are fine I guess, but oh my god am I sick of freehand circles, waffles, unicorns, and the like. </anypopularityimayhavehad>

Comment: @alex: [llamas are harder](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/38676/close-reasons-have-gone-missing-previously-closed-as-such-affected)

Comment: @greg: Screenshot added.

Comment: To use Jeff's words @beska: Perhaps this is not the site for you and you'd be happy somewhere else

Comment: Nice circles, +1. @beska, you are out!

Comment: What browser are you using? I see a CSS bug. The downvote part is floating too far down.

Comment: @Balus: most likely caused by the Waffle bug.

Comment: @Downvoter: Thanks for your concern, but I'll pull through somehow.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Could this be due to the voting anomaly script? Maybe you got a bunch of votes on your +8 answer that were counted as anomalies (i.e. coming from suspected sock puppet accounts, etc.) and were removed, but only after you already got a badge for it.

Maybe this could also be a byproduct of some errors I've been getting lately. I've noticed more often that clicking the voting arrows puts up a box saying an error occurred. Sometimes the vote is displayed as having been added (i.e. the total changes), sometimes not. Refreshing the page usually puts the score back to what it was before I voted, and I can then vote again without error. Maybe these errors are screwing things up behind the scenes.

**EDIT:** Looking at [the question Jeff linked to below](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/46706/something-broken-when-voting-up-and-accepting), the second explanation above may be the cause, especially since Benjol claims in the linked question to have successfully upvoted [an accepted answer from waiwai933](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/46703/how-can-i-sort-all-my-questions-by-date-or-by-time-when-they-where-asked/46704#46704) 10 times. That would be enough for an Enlightened badge (although the answer still displays only +2).

Comment: this is the most plausible IMO. Particularly in light of this: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/46706/something-broken-when-voting-up-and-accepting/46708#46708

Answer (score 4):

This is mysterious indeed.

At first I was thinking migrations, but I don't see *any* answers of yours that have >10 score and are accepted across any site in the trilogy!

edit: at some point that post had more than 10 votes, either because:

1. it was done through votes which were later removed as anomalous
2. erroneous denormalized count updates

In the case of #1, there's not a lot to do.

We did deploy improved code for #2 so the denormalized counts are always set via live queries of the votes table rather than a brain-damaged `.Score++`.

Comment: @Jeff it's not nice to censor us :)

Answer (score 1):

I loaned you one of mine.

<sup>You'll need to give it back when you're done with it, though. It's the only thing I wear when I make waffles for my unicorns.</sup>

Comment: I sense a feature request coming...

Comment: I've been wanting to edit one of Polly's posts for a long time now to attempt to get revenge :)

Comment: @Earlz: Fixed that for you. :D

Comment: @Jon much better :) I tried to get it even more memeish. @Pollyanna is a meme by his self though

Comment: @Pollyanna: That's an interesting [vote count you've got there](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/2915 "808").

Comment: @json wow, he has never voted a single person down..

Comment: @ear http://xkcd.com/725/

Comment: @Dow I don't understand how that comic has anything to do with what we were talking about

Comment: @Earlz: I think it references back to your first comment.

Comment: @Jon @Downvoter sucks at making jokes then...

Comment: It applies perfectly to your first comment, it's like that comic was made for me to put it here because of your first comment. @ear @jon

Comment: LOL! That's hilarious!